# Ror - Check if URL is AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to blacklist URL's that are AJAX for a login redirect.  I have the following code:

```
request.fullpath =~ /\A\/(login|sso_login|sign_out|auth)/
```

How can I use `xhr?` to request the fullpath **only** if the URL is not `xhr?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a guard to whatever this code does with `unless request.xhr?`